# Do I need to add a source to my map in order to use clustering?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I want to add clustering to my map from mapbox, I followed the getting started as they suggest:

https://www.mapbox.com/install/js/cdn-add/

And now I have a map, I also added some of my own markers, which are users from my backend that have lats and longs.

So I have a map and some markers.

Now, I want to add clustering, and in the example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/

they add a source:

```
map.addSource("earthquakes", {
})
```

which I don't have, and at this moment I don't think I even need. because I can see the tiles and my markers.

I thought about adding a source, but which source? I don't need a source, I already have what I needed, the tiles and the markers... but the cluster option is in the addSource method on the map. So.. I'm lost here.

This is what they show in the example, but as I said, I don't have or need any other source, as I already see the tiles and my markers, I just want to cluster.

````
map.addSource("earthquakes", {
type: "geojson",
data: "https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson",
cluster: true,
clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

I had to create a geoJson object from my users like this:

```
  const geoJsonMarkers = users.map( (place, i ) => {
    const [placeLng, placeLat] = place.location.coordinates;
    const position = { lat: placeLat, lng: placeLng };
    return {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [position.lng, position.lat]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": place.name
      }
    }
  })
  const usersArray = {
    "features": geoJsonMarkers
  }
```

And then pass it to the data property of the source like so:

```
  map.on('load', function() {
    // Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and set the
    // 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will add the point_count property to your source data.
    map.addSource("users", {
    type: "geojson",
    // Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ earthquakes
    // from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
    data: usersArray,
    cluster: true,
    clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
    clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
    });
     ...
```

the addSource name is arbitrary, could be anything in my case are users so I called it users.